# Xcode 11.4.1 Core Data model not recognised

Tags: swift, xcode, class, core-data

I'm trying to add core data to my existing project (I'm using Xcode 11.4.1). So I have added the following to my AppDelegate file:

```
    // MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {

            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {

            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the following simple model so far:

[image]

I have imported CoreData in my AppDelegate and my ViewController. However, I don't seem to be able to access this new model. When I try to create an instance of it as follows:

```
let newSheet = RefuelSheet()
```

I simply get an 'unresolved identifier' error.

My understanding was that because I have selected 'Class Definition' the relevant classes would automatically be created by XCode and I would be able to access this object.

I've tried cleaning the project and building for testing, but still no luck.

I've also checked that the data model file definitely has the same name as the persistent container defined in AppDelegate which it does.

Comment: Apart from the issue creating an instance with the default initializer will cause an error.

Comment: Thanks @vadian , so how should I be doing this?

Comment: You have to use one of the designated initializers but as I said it's not directly related to your problem.

Comment: Yeah this is the thing - I knew I'd have to alter that init but I would expect it to recognise the object type at least. Also, I tried searching for the class files which I thought would be under Library - Developer - Xcode - DerivedData - my project - Build - Intermediates - my project.build but they're not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xcode 11.4**

I created a new project and created your `xcdatamodel` as you have and Codegen set to **Class Definition**.  The only exception being the **Module** field in the Data Model Inspector is cleared and set to **Global namespace**.

After building the project, the `RefuelSheet` class was not recognised by the compiler.  Likewise following a Clean + Build.  However, I closed Xcode and upon reopening and building, the class was recognised.

If that doesn't work, try creating the class manually as well:

**Select your xcdatamodel > Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass**

Build the project and it should tell you the classes are created twice.  Now, delete the manually generated classes and Clean + Build again.

Personally, I always use manual codegen for `CoreData` classes because it gives more fine-grained control with Types (particularly with relationships), and custom functions.

As an aside, when you create an instance of a `CoreData` class, you need to use one of the designated initialisers, typically `(context:)`:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let moc = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let newSheet = RefuelSheet(context: moc)
```

Comment: thank you! I restarted xcode and it found it straight away!!! I should've known the old 'turn it off and on again' would be the answer haha. Thanks again